# LINQ join on a subquery with a union

Tags: c#, linq, t-sql

```
      from mstr in m_db.master_records
      join loctab in
      (
          from bp in m_db.basepay_records
          select new { empID = bp.p_empid, loc = bp.p_loc }
      )
      .Union
      (
          from ass in m_db.emp_assignments
          select new { ass.a_emp, ass.a_loc }
      )
       on mstr.prem_emp = loctab.empID
```

Getting an error on the last line, saying loctab is not in scope.  I have played with it a bit, but I can't see a different way to do it.

Comment: One thing would be that the "=" should read "equals".

Comment: Also, there's no select on the outer query. It's weird that it tells you loctab would be out of scope because I don't think it is.

Comment: Very difficult to analyse without having the database, but you should probably be looking to declare the first query with join/on and then union the second one. You could declare them seperately if need be. query1WithJoin.Union(query2).

Comment: It was the equals thing.  Thank you all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You last line should read like this.

```
on loctab.empID equals mstr.prem_emp
select //... perform your select on the unioned tables.
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what "not in scope" means here, but there's one thing wrong. Both anonymous types should have exactly the same definition, otherwise you can't Union:

You have:

```
select new { empID = bp.p_empid, loc = bp.p_loc }
```

Then also use:

```
select new { empID = ass.a_emp, loc = ass.a_loc }
```

Maybe the exception message was a disguised way of telling this.